# Экспорт значения одного свойства CSS в другой

Tags: php, css, веб-программирование

Допустим, надо настроить ширину и высоту `div`. Ширина равна 20% от родительского `div`. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы значение высоты автоматически выставлялось от уже рассчитанного в пикселях значения ширины.
Это можно как-либо реализовать штатными средствами или через PHP? Я слышал, что это можно реализовать через SASS, но нет возможности установить его на хостинг.

Comment: Вы хотите сделать квадрат или о чём речь?

Comment: @andreymal Есть `div` с условной шириной `100%`. Есть дочерний элемент с шириной `20%`. Как получить значение, которое составляет `20%` дочернего элемента, но применить этот размер к другому элементу.

Comment: К **другому** элементу? Скорее всего никак

Comment: Да, я хочу сделать квадратный div

Comment: Для квадратного div достаточно просто воткнуть [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) наверное?

Comment: Да, оно работает